# Django REST framework test case order

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I want to test the APIs of a Django app. For example I have these APIs:

- /user/register/
- /user/login/

I wrote test.py like this:

```
class UserTest(APITestCase):

   def test_register(self):
      # ...
      # self.assertEqual( ... )

   def test_login(self):
      # ...
      # login with registered user (test_register function)
```

The **test_register** works properly but **test_login** does not work.

The user that I created in **test_register** not exists in database when **test_login** running.

How can I keep the state of database in test process?

And how can I set the running order for test class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unittests should be independent from each other, and therefore order should not matter.
If you need an action to be performed before every test, like creating a brand new user, you should put it in the `setUp` function

Then if you need your user to be registered for the login test, simply do it manually within the test. Basically:

- `test_register` is to TEST the register workflow
- `test_login` is to TEST the login workflow, and you can manually set the registered status there (you're not testing it here)

```
class UserTest(APITestCase):
   
   def setUp(self):
       # call super().setUp() if necessary
       self.user = User.objects.create_user(**your_data)
       # More stuff

   def test_register(self):
      # ...
      # self.assertEqual( ... )

   def test_login(self):
      self.user.register() # or any action required
      # ...
      # login with registered user (test_register function)
```

Edit:
Just FYI, there are 4 very useful hooks in test cases:

- `setUpClass`: Happens before the FIRST test
- `setUp`: Happens before EVERY test
- `tearDown`: Happens after EVERY test
- `tearDownClass`: Happens after the LAST test

You'll often use the `setUp` function to prepare your DB and what not (as it gets reset after every test automatically)

Comment: And specifically for Django: setUpTestData and the fixtures class attribute.